# Translating Code into Math?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, translation-request

This is my first posting here, so I am not sure this is in the correct place.

I have this math problem:
Find the number of distinct integers in this set:

$$\left\{\left[\frac{1^2}{5012}\right], \left[\frac{2^2}{5012}\right],\ldots, \left[ \frac{5012^2}{5012}\right]\right\},$$

where $[x]$ denotes the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.

I am not very familiar with the mathematical notation involved with this problem, so I wrote a computer program that solves it (in Java)

I get the correct answer: 3760, and I get the entire set of distinct integers. 
But I do not know how to represent this mathematically. Any help is appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, it looks like you are asking a Java question here. I'd suggest that you either do this in stackoverflow or computer science. I'd say this isn't the place to ask such a question. I'm a programmer, so I know how you feel...there will probably be more help there.

Comment: I don't think this is a Java question at all. The Java code is simply one way of getting the answer, and the OP is asking for a different (mathematical) way.

Comment: I don't think the logic used in your Java code is suitable for a mathematical argument. Basically, your logic is "compute all the numbers and save the distinct ones". But, if you look at the numbers your code produces (both before and after removing duplicates), you might see some patterns that help you create a mathematical argument.

Comment: @loganmath196: This is actually a nice question, but I would recommend updating it (delete the Java) and restating it as:

I am trying to find a mathematical argument to solve this problem.

I need to find the total number of distinct integers that are generated by:

$$\lfloor \frac{i^2}{5012} \rfloor$$

for $i$ ranging from 1 to 5012.

I wrote a Java program and was able to find the distinct integers and the total number of 3760, but I have not figured out how to make a mathematical argument. 

Can anyone provide guidance/hints?

Comment: Thank you folks for your help, I have updated my post. Any ideas on how to represent this mathematically?

Comment: Mathematically, the number of distinct integers in your set is simply denoted $\Big\lvert\big\{\lfloor i^2/5012\rfloor:i\in\{1,2,\ldots,5012\}\big\}\Big\rvert$. But this doesn't represent your logic at all.

Comment: @loganmath196 I'd also suggest changing the title of this post to reflect your rewrite.

Comment: First thought. For any integer $k$ every number $n$ satisfying $k\cdot 5012 \leq n^2  < (k+1)5012$ will produce $k$ under the given operation. Taking the square root we have $\sqrt{5012k} \leq n < \sqrt{(k+1)5012}$. So it should just be the matter of summing these intervals carefully.

Answer (score 5):

There are two regimes here.  We know the gap between squares grows as the square root grows larger.   As long as the gap between $k^2$ and $(k+1)^2$ is less than $5012$ we will hit every integer because the gaps between the fractions is less than $1$.  When the gap is larger than $5012$, the integers will all be distinct.  As the gap between $k^2$ and $(k+1)^2$ is $2k+1$, it becomes larger than $5012$ at $k=2506$.  So in the set we have every integer from $0$ through $\frac {2506^2}{5012}=1253$, or $1254$ of them, and then all the ones from $\lfloor \frac {2507^2}{5012}\rfloor$ through $\lfloor \frac {5012^2}{5012}\rfloor$, or $2506$ of them, a total of $3760$.